# Taking a derivative of a function wrt time, when t is not itself a variable (just a subscript).

Tags: calculus, economics

This is in an economics setting, where I have a standard Cobb Douglas function that puts output in terms of technology, labour and capital:

$$Y_t=A_tK_t^{\alpha}L_t^{1-\alpha}$$

[Function to be differentiated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJdjy.png)

I can take the partial derivative of the A, K and L terms easily, but how do I obtain dY/dt?
My notes say to use product rule, but the t is only a subscript not a variable.

Comment: Don't let notation fool you.  You haven't told us what the terms in your expression mean, but presumably something like $A_t$ means that $A$ is a function of $t$.  That is to say, $A_t$ could be rewritten as $A(t)$.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. All the terms change over time so I suppose in that sense they are functions of time as you point out. But that function isn't specified, so my final answer will have, for example, a dA/dt term in it because I'm not able to evaluate that further. Maybe that isn't a problem.

Comment: Sure, that's not unusual.  In such cases the issue tends to be that you want to know how the rate of change of one term affects the rate of change of some other term.

Answer (score 2):

Logarithmic differentiation gives

$$\frac{\dot{Y_t}}{Y_t}=\frac{\dot{A_t}}{A_t}+\alpha \frac{\dot{K_t}}{K_t}+(1-\alpha)\frac{\dot{L_t}}{L_t}\\
\implies\dot{Y_t}=Y_t\left(\frac{\dot{A_t}}{A_t}+\alpha \frac{\dot{K_t}}{K_t}+(1-\alpha)\frac{\dot{L_t}}{L_t}\right).$$

Also, $t$ is a variable; the use of subscripts is just notation.